# how can I transfer files between 2 windows based pc's via bluetooth automatically

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I have to transfer files between two computers both windows based and have paired the two using bluetooth adapters.

my concern is i have to transfer files from one to another. can someone suggest a software/code so that this can be done automatically without the need to manually send/receive the file every time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in command line in Windows to do that but you can use:

[btobex](http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/btobex.html)

Which can be used that way:

```
btobex -n"ComputerB" picture.jpg picture1.jpg
```

Also have a look in:

http://bluetoothinstaller.com/bluetooth-command-line-tools/